# Converting uint8 array to a cv2 readable image

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, opencv

I have a large array of 50K images saved as 3*1024 arrays (RGB 32X32) and I want to convert them into cv2 format.

```
# Here I read the images
def unpickle(file):
    import cPickle
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = cPickle.load(fo)
    return dict


def my_main():
    print 'unpicking training set images'
    d = unpickle(pickled_training_files)
    print 'reshaping the images to 5 sets of 10,000 images (RGB - 3*32*32)'
    training_set_images = d.itervalues().next().reshape((5,10000,3,32,32))
    print 'loading image with opencv'
    tmp_img = training_set_images[0][0]
    print tmp_img.dtype # result is uint8

my_main()
```

How should I continue? I tried everyting I've seen here on SO but nothing helped

In particular, the thing I'm trying now is to play with the 2nd parameter in `cv2_img = cv2.imdecode(tmp_img, )` but the result is always `None`

Comment: 3*1024 for a 32x32 pixel RGB image sounds like it's just raw pixel data. `imdecode` is unnecessary in that case, as there's no image format to decode. What's the problem right now?

Comment: Where is your saving code? Or how do you save it?